# Send Multi-Part Email from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, email, multipart

I am creating an iPhone app where the user can send their work in an e-mail to whomever they wish. It is easy enough to open the Mail App using the openURL method of UIApplication.

```
NSString* lsMailToStr = @"mailto:?subject=Subject!&body=Body";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:lsMailtoStr]];
```

However, it would be nice to provide a plain text fallback for those e-mail programs that don't support HTML e-mail. Is there a way to open the Mail App and have it send an e-mail that is multi-part (contains both text/plain and text/html)?

Are there other arguments other than "body=" that can be supplied to the Mail App that will allow this?

Comment: I know this is possible. I've seen that Adam Rosenfield is doing this in Word Fu (awesome game, btw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that iPhone OS 3.0 is here, there is new API for sending email in-app. It doesn't appear to support what you want, except possibly through the support for adding attachments. I suggest you file a bug requesting this enhancement.